# How order of stuctural breakpoints is decided?

Tags: structural-change

Using 'breakpoints' command in R, I got multiple breakpoints. Yet if I limited the number of breakpoints to 1. It gives just a single breakpoint as desirable. How is this 1st breakpoint is decided and also order of other breakpoints arranged?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on the question you are analyzing. As it stands, it is not easy to answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton sir! I have just discovered that order of 'm' is based on least TSS (Total Sum of Square). The breakpoint that gives least TSS after break is considered 1st breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm implemented in `breakpoints()` (from the `strucchange` package) estimates the optimal location of $m$ breakpoints for $m = 1, \dots, \mathtt{breaks}$. Optimality is in the sense of minimal residual sum of squares. The reason is that the underlying computations are mostly the same, no matter whether $m$ is 2 or 3 or ... Therefore, from a single fitted `breakpoints` result, you can extract the optimal location of $m = 1$ breakpoint, $m = 2$ breakpoints etc. Often, the breakpoint locatation for $m = 1$ is one of the two locations for $m = 2$ but this does not have to be the case.

Hence, there is no ordering problem. The practitioner has to answer two questions: (1) What is the number of breakpoints $m$? (2) And given the number $m$, what are the corresponding breakpoint locations?

The `breakpoints()` function answers this by splitting it up: Question (2) has a unique well-defined answer (in the least squares sense) for every given $m$. Hence, the optimal breakpoint locations for a range of $m$ values are determined first. Subsequently, the best $m$ can be chosen by information criteria or by expert knowledge etc.

Other algorithms such as the PELT algorithm implemented in the `changepoints` package solve both questions in a single run by only returning the solution for the $m$ that is optimal with respect to a certain information criterion.

Comment: Thanks a ton sir!
I have just discovered that order of 'm' is based on least TSS (Total Sum of Square). The breakpoint that gives least TSS after break is considered 1st breakpoint.

Comment: No, the TSS is not used. The location of the breakpoints _given_ their number m is selected by minimizing the residual sum of squares (RSS). And the _default_ number of locations m is selected by minimizing the BIC. Both quantities are reported in the object returned and you can easily employ other information criteria for the selection if you wish to do so.